# Using JSON to parse Rally rest api service results

Tags: apex, json

How do i use JSON to parse out the following result i get back from Rally's web service api.

```
{"QueryResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources."], "TotalResultCount": 4, "StartIndex": 1, "PageSize": 200, "Results": [{"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task/16883055138", "_refObjectUUID": "038c4641-71f7-4a95-a663-3555a3c369dc", "_objectVersion": "5", "_refObjectName": "Validated the changes in SO Request Section", "Name": "Validated the changes in SO Request Section", "Actuals": 1.0, "State": "Completed", "_type": "Task"}, {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task/16947438122", "_refObjectUUID": "c58b3dfb-50a4-414c-94d0-d341181c7d15", "_objectVersion": "5", "_refObjectName": "Change WAD list to show only opportunities", "Name": "Change WAD list to show only opportunities", "Actuals": 1.0, "State": "Completed", "_type": "Task"}, {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task/16947441630", "_refObjectUUID": "727b8a6c-1305-416a-a237-1ebeaddf515e", "_objectVersion": "5", "_refObjectName": "Add new fields to Opportunity", "Name": "Add new fields to Opportunity", "Actuals": 1.0, "State": "Completed", "_type": "Task"}, {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task/16949115293", "_refObjectUUID": "c057615e-7a5a-4f05-a600-56b4c565ad36", "_objectVersion": "2", "_refObjectName": "Validate the changes", "Name": "Validate the changes", "Actuals": null, "State": "Defined", "_type": "Task"}]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deserialize the response body you are getting. To achieve that you need to use the apex [JSON](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/Chunk1233280440.htm#apex_class_System_Json) lib.

From my view the easiest method is use [json.deserializeUntyped](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped.htm)

Sample

```
    Http h = new Http();
    Httpresponse resp = h.send(req);
    system.debug('resp:'+resp);
    system.debug('respBody:'+resp.getBody());
    Map<String,Object> jsonResp = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());
    Map<String,Object> res = (Map<String,Object>) jsonResp.get('QueryResult');
    List<Object> results = ((List<Object>)) results.get('Results');

    for(Map<String,Object> r: results){
       system.debug('NAme: '+r.get('Name'));
       system.debug('State: '+r.get('State')); 
        //rest ..... 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, made a few changes : `Map<String,Object> jsonResp = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    Map<String,Object> qres = (Map<String,Object>) jsonResp.get('QueryResult');
  List<Object> resultsObject = (List<Object>)qres.get('Results'); for(Object r: resultsObject ){
        Map<String,Object> testResult=( Map<String,Object>) r;
       system.debug('NAme: '+testResult.get('Name'));
       system.debug('State: '+testResult.get('State'));  }`

Comment: But i had a question , the 'Results' will be different based on what i add in the query to the service, so do i have to modify the parsing every time ?